# JQuery issues with SharePoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am having a strange problem with jQuery inside sharepoint. My jQuery code works fine in Web Applications but when I use the same code on a Web Part it creates problem.

Here is the problem with jQuery in Web Parts. I have external JavaScript file which I reference on my web part.

This is my function in a separate JavaScript file.

```
function CallJS() {

    alert($("#txt1")); **// It returns the object**
    alert($('#txt1').attr('value')); **// Always return 'undefined'**
    return false;
}
```

My development environment is VS2008, SharePoint 2007 and jQuery version is 1.4.4.

Comment: it means the value property of your object is not defined or not set

Comment: As a side note .val() should return the value in jquery as well.

Comment: Yes it should be working but its not unfortunately. It gives 'undefined' always.

Comment: Doesn't matter I try to set the value and then try to get the value. Result is same 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

First try to pass value using jquery attribute like this `$('#txt1').attr('value','Test')`
after passing value try this `$('#txt1').attr('value')` it returs your value.

In you case solution is that use `$('#txt1').val()`, or try to pass value dynamically than you can access that value using attribute method.